# Install Node.js 4 on Alpine Linux

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I am new to Alpine Linux and I tried to install Node.js 4.

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1055060/how-to-install-a-specific-package-version-in-alpine) I can specify the version like this:

```
apk add nodejs=4
```

I also tried this because I though maybe it doesn't understand semantic versions and I saw [here](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) that `4.3.0-r0` seems to be the only available version:

```
apk add nodejs=4.3.0-r0
```

Both commands lead to an error:

> ```
> ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
>   nodejs-6.2.0-r0:
>     breaks: world[nodejs=4.3.0-r0]
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to list available packages:

```
apk search --update 'node*'
```

choose one and install it as next:

```
apk add nodejs-lts --update

(1/4) Installing libgcc (5.3.0-r0)
(2/4) Installing libstdc++ (5.3.0-r0)
(3/4) Installing libuv (1.9.1-r0)
(4/4) Installing nodejs-lts (4.4.4-r0)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how my assumptions were wrong?

Comment: It’s named `nodejs-lts` only in v3.4, it’s just `nodejs` in further versions or `nodejs-current` for the “current” version (that’s the upstream’s terminology, it’s non-LTS version).

Answer (score 2):

Alpine is a rolling release distro.
Packages for nodejs are dependent from which version of alpine you are using.

In your example, if you need nodejs-4.3x, you should use Alpine 3.3:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=

This because there is no way yet to install arbitrary an older versions of a package from official repositories.

A possible workaround, if it might be fitting for you, is using an lxc container, where you can specify the alpine version to use, with a small footprint on the host.

Comment: Alpine is **not** a rolling release distro. Only edge branch is rolling.